# How to write inputs append with time using panda in python

Tags: python, pandas, time, lstm

I have a data csv file include with three inputs temperature, humidity and wind. So in this csv file first input recorded at 6:00:00a.m.

But I want to start my time as 0 and then my second time is `start_time+60 (minutes)`

Here is the code  when `start time = 0`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
df['datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'], format='  %d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S')
first = df.groupby('date')['datetime'].transform('first')
df['new']= df['datetime'].sub(first).dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
print(df['new'])
```

result:`0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360, 465, 540, 600, 660, 720, 780, 840, 930 ,0`

my csv file:

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KsAtm0vSsBfOL8z42UAPAwljaO1-DSKfdD9lSu3lv80/edit#gid=35707506)

image of my csv file:

[image]

According to this result you can see that in new column `start_time==0` and then my second time `start_time+60`.

This will continue till to next day `start_time`. Then next day `start_time` will become again `0`.

I'm going to predict value using neural network.
So I wrote the time code.
But I want to write the code, when time will be 0,60,120,180 minutes..... then inputs are appended to these time.

So if we take 
`start_time as (t0)`

`inputs (x,x1...)['temperatue','humidity','wind']`

when ;

`t0 + 0 = 0` `min =  t0`:

- x.append =[first inputs in csv file] [x= ['63','0','0']]

`t0 + 60 = 60` `min = t1` :

- x1.append =['63','0','2']

`t1 + 60 = 120` `min = t2`

- x2.append =['104','11','0']

`t2 + 60 = 180` `min = t3`

- x3.append =['93','0',50']

For the more understanding I paste the image with csv file :

[image]

Like this I want to put these inputs into the neural network to predict the next future temperature value in every 60 minutes.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What output you are expecting? what inputs you consider?  not cler about it.

Comment: @ Amazing Things Around You Sorry I forgot  to  write it output is temperature value in next 60 min.

Comment: @anks_91 Here I pasted my data csv file link.

Comment: @knh190 Done I formatted it.

Comment: Still not fixed at the end of your post.

Comment: @knh190 I only wrote the time code. At the end of post I wrote what I want to write it as a code with time

Comment: Perhaps I am just being thick but I have no idea what you are talking about, even more so after "What I expected is like this:"

Comment: @Goyo Actually what I want to write that in my csv file start time=6:00:00 a.m  and inputs are ['63','0','0'] , so on.. So I want to predict future temperature value using neural network in every 60 min.  For that I want to say , when I include the first inputs to the neural network at that time my start_time(t0)  = 0. Then next (second input) inputted to the network after 60 minutes from start_time to the network. Then my third input inputted to next 120 min. This will contnously run till to next day start_time.

Comment: @Goyo Then next _day start_time will be again 0 and then data input to the network in every 60 min.  This is the process what I am trying to do. But I didn't have any idea how to code this with the time , that I wrote .